# I accidently filled out wrong designation for letter of recommendation

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

In my application form, I filled out the staff's designation as "Associate Professor" but in the recommendation form that my faculty filled out for me, she mentioned her designation as "Professor" which is the correct one.
I am worried whether this would make my recommendation look suspicious and be denied an admission based on this.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a simple mistake and a minor thing. Update the information if possible, perhaps with a separate communication, but don't worry about it.

You will be accepted or rejected based on much more fundamental and important things.

I'd guess that such things happen often enough when someone is on the verge of promotion in any case. The professor's letter might actually mention their current academic rank, in fact.

Relax.